# PowerShell doesn't recognize string correctly

Tags: vb.net, powershell, ffmpeg

I'm passing a command to powershell

```
Dim command As String
command = "ffmpeg -vsync 0 –hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid –resize 1280x720 -i D:\Imagens\nova\bol.mkv -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M D:\Imagens\nova\bol_encod.mkv"
```

with

```
Dim powerShell As String = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    Process.Start("powershell", "-noexit " + command)
```

but powershell returns

> Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ÔÇôhwaccel' ÔÇôhwaccel:
>   Invalid argument

where I believe 'ÔÇôhwaccel' to be –hwaccel; That's completely strange, once when I past the code directly on PowerShell it works fine.

Is that a problem with my string?

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: a copy paste of the source command into powershell 5]

I'm assuming powershell 5 and not core, I copied the test and pasted it into the terminal and found this u instead of a '-'. I would start by retyping and avoiding what looks like it may be a long hyphen or something else which is breaking the terminal.

Comment: Thank you! The long hyphen was the problem, I was quite confident because I got the code directly from Nvidia Guide "ffmpeg -vsync 0 –hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid –resize 1280x720 -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M output.mp4" https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/. Problem solved! thank you!